# Centralizar submenu com menu

Tags: css, html5

```css
/*Sub-Menu*/

.menu.superior .nivel-dois, .menu.superior .nivel-dois, .menu.superior .nivel-um li:hover .nivel-dois{display: contents;po;position: unset;}

.pagina-login .menu.superior, .pagina-busca .menu.superior, .pagina-carrinho .menu.superior{ display: relative; }

.menu li.com-filho{
 position:inherit;
}
.menu.superior .nivel-dois{display:none;position:absolute;top:103px;text-align:center;left:auto;margin-left: auto;min-width:auto;width:140px;/*background:#fff;*/}
.menu.superior .nivel-dois a{font-weight:bold;color:#564119;margin-top:3px;background:#fff;width:157px;margin-left: auto;}
.menu .nivel-dois, .menu .nivel-tres, .menu.lateral .nivel-um>li>a{
background:transparent;
}

.todas-menu-1{
background:transparent;
margin-left:-35px;
}

/*Fim do SubMenu */



.menu.superior .nivel-um>li{ 
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  
}

.menu.superior .nivel-um>li{ 
    border: 0 none;
    float: center;
    margin-left:5px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    display:block; 
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.7;
    height:73px;
    width:127px;
    margin-top:8px;
}
.menu.superior .nivel-um>li:hover{ margin-top: 0;}
.menu.superior .icon-chevron-down, .menu.superior .icon-chevron-right{ display: none;}

/*  line-height: 30px; */
.menu.superior .nivel-um>li a strong{ 
    color: #f9f9f8;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform:unset;
    margin-top:40px;
    font-family:product-sans-regular;
    font-weight:normal;
} 

.menu.superior .nivel-um>li:hover a strong{ color: #eda302;}


/* Menu Interno */

.pagina-inicial #cabecalho .menu .nivel-um{ display:inline-block;  padding-left:5px; }
.pagina-inicial #cabecalho .menu .engloba-topo:hover .nivel-um{display:inline-block;}
.menu.superior > ul{ text-align: center; }
```

CASO QUEIRA VER DIRETAMENTE NO SITE

https://www.lojaviral.com.br/

Comment: Informa o HTML tambem.

Comment: A loja integrada não permite o acesso ao HTML, apenas ao css

Comment: qualquer duvida tem o site aqui;
https://www.lojaviral.com.br/

Comment: Evite caps.. ;)

Comment: ja troquei, to querendo ajuda no meu codigo

Comment: O problema é no último botão do submenu que está desalinhado?

Comment: tambem, mas ele ta em todos

Answer (score 0):

O botão precisa ser reposicionado com `!important` porque outra regra está tendo mais prioridade. No arquivo `avancado.css` altere a classe abaixo referente ao botão para:

```
.todas-menu-1{
background:transparent;
margin-left:-15px !important;
}
```

Comment: Quando entro em alguns navegadores ele fica todo desajustado.
Mas essa parte ta certinho.